# Problem on Homomorphism, isomorphism, and dot product.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

For $x ∈ R^n$, deﬁne $λ_x : R^n → R$ by $λ_x(y) = x · y$

(a) Show that $λ_x ∈ Hom_R(R^n, R)$.

(b) Show that the map $x → λ_x$ establishes an isomorphism between $R^n$ and $Hom_R(R^n, R)$.

(c) Show that if {$v_1,v_2, . . . ,v_n$} is a basis for $R^n$, then {$λ_{v_1}, λ_{v_2} , . . . , λ_{v_n}$} is a basis for $Hom_R(R^n, R)$.

for part (a), I just showed that $λ_x$ was a linear transformation. Meaning it respects vector addition and scalar multiplication.

For part (b), I am a bit unsure of how to do this. I can see that the map is equivalent to $R^n → R$, and that is exactly what $Hom_R(R^n,R)$ does, but I don't know how to express it past an intuition. I thought of perhaps saying that both the given map and $Hom_R(R^n,R)$ can be expressed by $1$x$n$ matrix multiplication with a column vector in $R^n$, so I could perhaps conclude that it is of $dim(R^{1xn})$, or equivalently, $dim(R^n)$. Since the dimensions are the same, I can conclude $R^n$ is isomoprhic to $Hom_R(R^n,R)$. Does this work?

For part (c), I was just thinking that since $R^n$ is isomorphic to $Hom_R(R^n,R)$, I could say that each vector in the basis $v_i$ will be mapped to a unique element in $R$, corresponding to $λ_{v_i}$. Thus {$λ_{v_1}, λ_{v_2} , . . . , λ_{v_n}$} forms a basis for $Hom_R(R^n,R)$. But I'm not quite sure if I really showed what they wanted here.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For (b), it is simpler than you think it is.  Just show injectivity and surjectivity of the correspondence; i.e., that if \lambda_{x}=\lambda_{y}, then show in detail why x necessarily equals y.  Next show that every linear functional on R^n is necessarily a linear combination of the \lambda_{e_{i}}, where e_{i} is the ith standard basis vector.

Comment: Doesn't $λ_x = λ_y$ imply that for some vector $v$, $<x,v> = <y,v>$, which doesn't necessarily mean that $x = y$. Unless I'm not actually understanding what lambda means.

Comment: $\lambda_x = \lambda_y$ implies that $<x,v> = <y,v>$ for every $v$, not just some $v$.

Comment: Yes, peter a g is correct.  Now, the set of all vectors v includes in particular the standard basis vectors.  The dot product of x with the ith basis vector is the ith coordinate of v.  Try taking the assumption that $\lambda_{x}-\lambda_{y}=0$ and try to show that the ith coordinate of x-y is 0, for all i.

Comment: I am just not seeing how to show that it's true. I tried expressing v in the dot product as a linear combination of the standard basis elements, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I was left with $c_1(x_1-y_1)+...+c_n(x_n-y_n) = 0$. Which to me, doesn't seem to show that x = y, since the constants could be anything